# Creating mapper for custom user storage SPI

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services

I would like to know if it's possible to create some mappers like there are with the ldap provider (like `full-name-ldap-mapper`, `user-attribute-ldap-mapper`, `group-ldap-mapper` ...) for a custom SPI.

I tried to make some stuff like creating a file under `resources\META-INF\services` and I've created the files that we need to map the attributes.

[image: Ressources tree]

I've searched on the doc and I don't find any information about implementation of SPI mapper.
I can create a custom storage provider though.

Thanks for your help!